# UILabel properties dump

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with properties set in `IB` (like custom font, shadow color, text color etc). I wanted to print all the properties of this `UILabel` to enable me to use the same set of properties on a different screen inside a `UITableViewCell` `textLabel` property. How do I print all the properties that I have set in my first screen to use it with the `textLabel` property inside `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Maybe you could use KVO to observe which properties you modified.

Comment: Don't you remember what you have set ??

Answer (score 1):

I find a `Cmd-C` and `Cmd-V` to copy and paste the `UILabel` from one Interface Builder XIB to the other usually copies the properties over as well.

I would imagine the same works for Storyboard too. Copying from one `ViewController` to another.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards. I was able to almost make it similar to the first screen label except that I'm missing one little thing. Since I'm using the textLabel property inside the UITableCell, I'm adding properties programmatically. But for the first one I added properties thru IB. The missing or the incorrect one is the shadow offset. I was also able to add this programmatically on the textLabel but still doesn't look identical to the IB based setting although it looks darn close.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to set properties for label on 1st screen.

```
-(void) setLabelProperties: (UILabel *) myLabel{
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
//set other properties
}
```

Call the same method on your

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

setLabelProperties(cell.textLabel);
}
```